# Parse Json data using Retrofit and Gson

Tags: android, retrofit2, gson

When I make a API call using Retrofit, I am getting the below JSON response.

[image]

Now I want to map data into a model. What's the best way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Here's the real JSON response.

```
{
"status": "success",
"data": {
    "messages": [],
    "result": {
        "clinicCode": "Medics",
        "firstName": "Charles",
        "lastName": "Sanders",
        "officeId": 0,
        "id": 7811,
        "startDate": 1508139082929,
        "timeZoneId": 0,
        "userDetailId": 6,
        "userName": "charles",
        "jobTitle": {
            "id": 1,
            "text": "Doctor",
            "count": 1
        },
        "isSuperUser": false,
        "clientId": 10,
        "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.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.Zd0TwwjP_HjzfgQzfS_-QIAXQ1F8TNTxFMSpve5VRWo",
        "employeeId": 14,
        "isActive": false,
        "isLocked": false,
        "lastPasswordChanged": 0,
        "sessionId": 0
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to generate POJO for you json response

Comment: can you post real Json in place of screenshot

Comment: You can download gsonFormat plugin in your android studio to map the response onto your model class

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a model classes for the response. Make use of online POJO generator (http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/).Set the annotation style in the generator option as GSON.
2. Copy the model classes to your project.
3. Set the model class as the Template class of the Call for your service
4. Retrofit would map the json to the Model class defined in the Call and return the same as the body in onResponse() method of the retrofit.Callback class.

Comment: I did as described. But the problem is my callback is never getting called although I am getting the response which I can see using the logging interceptor.